# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined when checking is value is equal to zero React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Sudoku board represented by a 2d array where zeros represent empty spaces which looks like this:

```
this.state = {
    board: [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    ]
}
```

I want to check that the board passes all the Sudoku rules (i.e. none of the same number in a column). I iterate through all of the values in the board and run a `positionIsValid` function on them which returns true if the position is valid on the board (I know this works from tests).

Obviously, this returns false on a good board as the zeros are included and so they will trigger as not valid. Due to this I simply added `currentBoard[i][j] !== 0` to the conditional however this is giving me the error TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined, pointing to that conditional.

I have tried to change the number used to represent a empty board space to 10 however the same issue persisted.

```
    boardIsValid() {
        const currentBoard = this.state.board;

        for (let i = 0; i < currentBoard.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < currentBoard[0].length; i++) {
                console.log(currentBoard[i][j]) // logs 0
                // We need to exclude zeros from the check as they represent empty squares
                if (currentBoard[i][j] !== 0 && !this.positionIsValid(currentBoard[i][j], [i, j])) return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    positionIsValid(num, position) {
        return this.rowIsValid(num, position) &&
            this.columnIsValid(num, position) &&
            this.boxIsValid(num, position);
    }

    rowIsValid(num, position) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.board[0].length; i++) {
            if (this.state.board[position[0]][i] === num && position[1] !== i) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    columnIsValid(num, position) {
        for (let i = 0; i< this.state.board.length; i++) {
            if (this.state.board[i][position[1]] === num && position[0] !== i) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    boxIsValid(num, position) {
        const box_x = Math.floor(position[1] / 3);
        const box_y = Math.floor(position[0] / 3);

        for (let i = box_y * 3; i < box_y * 3 + 3; i++) {
            for (let j = box_x * 3; j < box_x * 3 + 3; j++) {
                if (this.state.board[i][j] === num && [i, j] !== position) return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your loops. remember that it's 0 based. So the first item in the array is indexed at 0 not 1, so when the loops reach the end and the value reached the conditional of `i < currentBoard.length` then it's already out of bounds. So you should change it to either: `i <= currentBoard.length` or `i < currentBoard.length - 1`